# Issue with JSPTagException error using foreach comand in JSP

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I guess I have a general question about using the JSTL ForEach code on a JSP file.   Does the output in the "items" attribute have to be defined as an array?

I am currently getting an error message in my log saying it is a **"JSPTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach&gt"**;  I know I am getting output in the EFTresults variable but obviously not using it correctly.

Here is the JSP and JAVA program that I am using:

EFTscreen.jsp:

```
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Schedule Number</th>
                                <th>Contract Year</th>
                                <th>Creation Date</th>
                                <th>Num of Pay Recs</th>
                                <th>Schedule Total</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Status Date</th>
                                <th>Approval ID</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <c:forEach  var="row" items="${EFTresults}">
                             <tr>
                                 <td><c:out value="${row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" /></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${row.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" /></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${row.getCREATION_DATE()}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${row.getNUM_OF_PAY_RECORDS()}"/></td>
                                 <td <c:out value="${row.getTOTAL_AMOUNT()}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${row.getSTATUS()}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${row.getSTATUS_DATE()}"/></td>
                                 <td><c:out value="${row.getAPPR_HUD_EMPLOYEE()}"/></td>
                              </tr>
                           </c:forEach>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

            </article>
```

Here is the code that is used to create the EFTresults information in my JAVA servlet:

EFTscreen.java:

```
if (wkScheduleNum != 0) 
            {
              Sum_EFTBean EFTresults = EFTQuery.selectSchedule(wkScheduleNum, wkContract) ;
              request.setAttribute("EFTresults", EFTresults);

              if (EFTresults.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER().equals(wkScheduleNum))
              {
                 request.setAttribute("EFTresults", EFTresults);
               }
              else
              {
                 message = ("no EFT schedule Number found - please try again");
                 request.setAttribute("message", message);
              }
            }  

    }
```

EFTQuery.java program:

```
    try {
        System.out.println("Before going to connection statement.  Continue");
        connection
                = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1, wkSchedule);
        ps.setInt(2, wkContract);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("Before checking the rs next part.  Continue");

        if (rs.next()) {

            System.out.println("Inside the recordset processing for SQL.  Continue");
            Sum_EFTBean results = new Sum_EFTBean() ;
            results.setSCHEDULE_NUMBER(rs.getInt("SCHEDULE_NUMBER"));
            results.setEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR(rs.getInt("EFT_CONTRACT_YEAR"));
            results.setCREATION_DATE(rs.getString("CREATION_DATE"));
            results.setNUM_OF_PAY_RECORDS(rs.getInt("NUM_OF_PAY_RECORDS"));
            results.setTOTAL_AMOUNT(rs.getDouble("TOTAL_AMOUNT"));
            results.setSTATUS(rs.getString("STATUS"));
            results.setSTATUS_DATE(rs.getString("STATUS_DATE"));
            results.setAPPR_HUD_EMPLOYEE(rs.getString("APPR_HUD_EMPLOYEE"));
            return results ; 
        } 
        else 
        {
            Integer EFTnotfound = 99999;
            Sum_EFTBean results = new Sum_EFTBean() ;
            results.setSCHEDULE_NUMBER(EFTnotfound);
            return results ; 
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        System.err.println(e);

        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        return null;
    } 
    finally 
    {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        //            pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
```

Thanks for any help on it.

Answer (score -1):

I would usually type my iteration variable like this, and then call my getters like this:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${EFTresults}">
<jsp:useBean id="row" scope="page" type="the.path.to.the.package" />
    <tr>
        <td><%= row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER %></td>
        ...
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```